# 3d scatter plot into 3d surface plot in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I have a function that returns an estimate (`est`) for values of `x`,`y` and `z`.

I am aiming for a 3d plot to visualise the relationship between x,y,z (axes) and est (color gradient). It seems to work for a 3d scatter plot but not a surface plot. Is it impossible to have a surface/area plot for this task? Can't we connect the points together to show one surface area?

Example below with `plotly` but happy to have a solution with any R package. Thanks.

```r
# my estimator function
estimator <- function(y, x, z, alpha = 0.05) {
  binom_est <- binom.test(y, x, conf.level = 1 - alpha)$estimate[[1]]
  numerator <- binom_est * (1 - z)
  denominator <- z * (1 - binom_est)
  gamma <- numerator / denominator
  result <-
    ifelse(is.infinite(gamma), 1, ifelse(
      is.na(gamma),
      NA,
      ifelse(
        is.numeric(gamma) & is.finite(gamma),
        (gamma - 1) /
          (gamma + 1)
      )
    ))
  return(result)
}

grid <- expand.grid(
  y = seq(0, 100, by = 10),
  x = seq(0, 100, by = 10),
  z = seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1)
) 

# retain only rows where x > y  and exclude z = 0
grid <- grid[grid$x > grid$y & grid$z > 0, ]
est <- sapply(1:nrow(grid), function(i) {
  estimator(grid[i, "y"], grid[i, "x"], grid[i, "z"])
})

grid <- cbind(grid, est)

library(plotly)
#3d scatter plot
p_scatter <- plotly::plot_ly(
  data = grid,
  x = ~ x,
  y = ~ y,
  z = ~ z,
  color = ~ est,
  type = 'scatter3d',
  mode = 'markers',
  symbol = "square", 
  colors = c("blue", "white", "red")
)

#3d surface plot
p_suface <- plotly::plot_ly(
  data = grid,
  x = ~ x,
  y = ~ y,
  z = ~ z,
  intensity = ~ est,
  colors = c("blue", "white", "red"),
  type = 'mesh3d' #surface not working
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Looking at the docs, in addition to x,y,z you might need i,j,k - https://plotly.com/r/3d-mesh/ and  https://plotly.com/r/reference/mesh3d/